# Own library to send email codeigniter

Tags: email, codeigniter

I have a problem creating my own librairie to send email.
This is my code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Send_email {

    private $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->library('email');
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
        }

    public function signup($info, $lang) {

         $CI->email->to($info['email']); 
        ...
         $CI->email->send();
         return TRUE;
    }

    public function newsletter($info, $lang) {

         $CI->email->from('xxx@xxx.om', 'Newsletter');
        ...
         $CI->email->send();
         return TRUE;
    }

}

/* End of file Send_email.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/libraries/Send_email.php */
```

I get the error:

> Message: Undefined property: Send_email::$load Filename:
>   libraries/Send_email.php Line Number: 9 Fatal error: Call to a member
>   function library() on a non-object ...

I tried `$this->CI->load->library('email');`
But I get the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

It seems that the librairie can't be loaded... I would like to load it from the construtor so I don't have to do it in each function.
If I load it from each function it works well..

Could you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize $CI before using it to load the email library...

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->library('email');
}
```

Comment: I tried but it was the same...
I have found the problem! So stupid error:
I had to call like that: `$this->CI->email->to`
  Thanks anyway Anthony!

Comment: Yeah all of your method calls need to be made like that as well.  Glad it's fixed.